# Trying to create an expression to count events depending on the date

Tags: forms, ms-access, formula

I'm trying to create an expression. It will be put inside a Text Box on an Access Forms. The idea behind is to show how many meetings occurred on the first, second and third month of the current quarter. The month that is going to be analyzed will changes as we enter in another quarter, but will always display all months of the current quarter, so, first quarter will show the meeting from January, when we get in the second quarter will show the values from April and so on.

This is the expression I wrote and trying to use but keep getting the #name? erro

```
=DCount("[Meeting Date]";"tblDPAR";"year([meeting date]) = year(now()) AND Month([meeting date]) = IIf(Month(Now())<=3;1;IIf(Month(Now())<=6;4;IIf(Month(Now())<=9;7;10))")
```

The displayed month Will change as well as the days go by.

Photo with the location where the `textbox` is located and the idea behind it.

[image]

EDIT: let say for example the current month is February, the first `txtbox` will show the values of January, the second `txtbox` shows the values of February and the third March value. When the current month goes to the second quarter the first `txtbox` will shows valuer from April, the second one may values and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use below expression to count meetings for 1st quarter means from January 1 to March 31. Then change criteria part of formula for other quarters.

```
 =DCount("[Meeting Date]","[tblDPAR]","[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now()),3,31) & "#")
```

[image]

Comment: Untested formula posted from mobile.

Comment: # symbol for date data type. If data would string type then we would use ' single quote. So # (hash) symbol to qualify parameter as date.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I don't know if I let it clear but, the range of filter will changes every time the current month changes of quarter, so it can't be fixed as you suggested. The first txtbox will be related to first month of the current quarter. it will look for values from January, in the second quarter the values of April, and so on

Comment: First use the formula and see if the result is correct. I am sure then you can change the formula for your further needs.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Gives me an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @RafaelCarvalho Check this formula working to me. Comma (,) and semicolon (;) depends on regional settings. I have used comma for my region. You may use semicolon (;) for your region. `=DCount("[Meeting Date]","[tblDPAR]","[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now()),1,1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now()),3,31) & "#")`

Comment: you was right, there was a comma in the middle of the formula that I didn't changed to semicolon, thanks. Your formula solved half of the problem, the quarterly report (Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4), but I still need help to figure it out how to break into the months of each quarter, and make it changes automatically with the name as the year pass by

Comment: @RafaelCarvalho You have to write formula for each text box individually for each month.

Answer (score 0):

I used as a base to solve my problem the answer @Harun24HR gave to me in comments.
His formula solved part of my problem, showed how many meetings occurred in each quarter of this year (last three textbox in my picture). The other half of the problem was to show how many meeting per month in each quarter, in a way that changes as the year goes by (second, third and fourth textbox). The formulas are:

For each quarter:

```
=DCount("[Meeting Date]";"[tblDPAR]";"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());1;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());3;31) & "#")
```

For each quarter month (in a way that changes the reported month as the year goes by):
First month:

```
=DCount("[Meeting Date]";"[tblDPAR]";IIf(Month(Now())>=1 And Month(Now())<=3;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());1;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());1;31) & "#";IIf(Month(Now())>=4 And Month(Now())<=6;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());4;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());4;31) & "#";IIf(Month(Now())>=7 And Month(Now())<=9;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());7;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());7;31) & "#";"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());10;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());10;31) & "#"))))
```

Second month:

```
=DCount("[Meeting Date]";"[tblDPAR]";IIf(Month(Now())>=1 And Month(Now())<=3;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());2;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());2;31) & "#";IIf(Month(Now())>=4 And Month(Now())<=6;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());5;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());5;31) & "#";IIf(Month(Now())>=7 And Month(Now())<=9;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());8;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());8;31) & "#";"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());11;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());11;31) & "#"))))
```

Third month:

```
=DCount("[Meeting Date]";"[tblDPAR]";IIf(Month(Now())>=1 And Month(Now())<=3;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());3;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());3;31) & "#";IIf(Month(Now())>=4 And Month(Now())<=6;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());6;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());6;31) & "#";IIf(Month(Now())>=7 And Month(Now())<=9;"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());9;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());9;31) & "#";"[Meeting Date]>= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());12;1) & "# AND [Meeting Date]<= #" & DateSerial(Year(Now());12;31) & "#"))))
```